# Facebook Connect + restful_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I've been following Stuart's tutorial at
http://www.madebymany.co.uk/tutorial-for-restful_authentication-on-rails-with-facebook-connect-in-15-minutes-00523

and have been having a problem:

- I get a NoMethodError in UsersController#link_user_accounts; Rails
  doesn’t seem to recognize “facebook_session”. I have facebooker
  installed and have successfully authenticated using the normal
  Facebook API methods.

Has anyone tried this before? Anyone know what might be wrong? It
seems that somehow the Facebooker library isn't getting fully
loaded...

Comment: Which Ruby on Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to integrate Facebook Connect authentication to your application, I would strongly recommend switching from restful_authentication to [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master).  It has an [addon](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect/tree/master) that gives you easy to use access to Facebook Connect.

You can download an example app that uses Authlogic [here](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/tree/master) to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

For the facebook-session to work, all files should be at the correct domain. Have you got all the files / libraries on the same domain?